# how to inser ViewPager in to Custom RecyclerView android

Tags: android-studio

how to inser ViewPager in to Custom RecyclerView android?
please help me .

```
  public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)

{

   View view = 
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mnlist , 
            parent, false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    return new ListViewHolder(view);
}
```

> What to write getSupportFragmentManager() ?

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) 
   {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
    ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new HomeFragment(),"a");
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "b");
    adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(),"c");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: `onCreateViewHolder()` method is intended to instantiate the `ViewHolder` only. A `ViewPager` inside a `RecyclerView` seems like an awful design combination, what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "what to write getSupportFragmentManager()" ?

Comment: I'm going to use a Custom recyclerView , that into a TabLayer.

Answer (score -1):

i write code following ,but not answer , Because "ForceClose Activity".

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ((ListViewHolder) holder).bindView(position);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(((AppCompatActivity) ctx).getSupportFragmentManager());
   viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

}
```

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
    private String[] tabTitles = new String[] {"Tab 1", "Tab 2"};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
               Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1 ;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2 ;
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```